# reformatting a string in javascript by adding break \n?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to create a function in javascript that will take a string of text as a paramater, and then format it for me by adding `\n` to the string, which will form paragraphs.

- each paragraph can only be 32 chars in length
- i have to make sure that the words are not cut in half, when going to the next paragraph"

example String:

```
"If we listened to our intellect, we'd never have a love affair. We'd never have a friendship. We'd never go into business, because we'd be cynical. Well, that's nonsense. You've got to jump off cliffs all the time and build your wings on the way down."
```

after format should be like:

```
If we listened to our intellect, \n
we'd never have a love affair. \n
We'd never have a friendship.\n
We'd never go into business, \n
because we'd be cynical. Well, \n
that's nonsense. You've got to  \n
jump off cliffs all the time and \n
build your wings on the way down"
```

I am not sure how i would approach this problem, and im not expecting anyone to solve the whole solution, i just want a starting point, i am having difficulties with how to deal with spaces and words, and when to insert the \n into the string.

Comment: first hit on google for "javascript word wrap": http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/wordwrap-for-javascript/

Comment: A good starting point would be to use String.split() and split it by the space character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an algorithm for you:

```
take your string; chop it up in two pieces: left (first 32 chars), right (the rest)
while right != empty
 if length(left) == 32
    while last character of left != space
       take last char off of left, prepend it to right

 print left
 new left = first 32 chars of right; right = rest
end while
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple for cycle keeping track of how many characters you've met since last newline char(or since the beginning of the text for the first line). Once this value goes over 32, iterate back to the first space and replace it with `\n`. Think of what to do if a word is more than 32 chars.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex worked for me:

```
str.match(/.{1,32}(\s+|$)/g).join("\n");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PZxNK/